# How to Change XLXS excel data into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjjmi.png)

How can I convert this XLXS excel file into following array format. Also I attached the Screenshot of Excel file. Please review it and let me know

I am using this library to fetch the data from Excel file which i have mentioned given below:-

```
require_once "EXCEL/simplexlsx.class.php";
$xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('EXCEL/Testingexcel.xlsx');
Excel Array
$xlsx->rows()
```

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Section / Department
            [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjjmi.png) => Notes
            [2] => No
            [3] => Great Offer
            [4] => Code
            [5] => Use Photo
            [6] => Item Number
            [7] => English Description
            [8] => Greek Description
            [9] => Price From
            [10] => Price
            [11] => Text1
            [12] => Exclusive Brand
            [13] => Date From
            [14] => Date To
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Chair
        [1] => Cover
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => etge
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP1
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => wefewf
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP2
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 1
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP3
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 12
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP4
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 13
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP5
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 14
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP6
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 15
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP7
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 16
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP8
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 17
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP9
        [5] => Y
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 18
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP10
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 19      
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 40%
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => Table
        [1] => cover
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 20
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 1+1
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP11
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 145
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 1+1
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => AP12
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => TITLE 1657
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 1+1
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
        [4] => 
        [5] => 
        [6] => 
        [7] => 
        [8] => 
        [9] => 
        [10] => 
        [11] => 
        [12] => 
        [13] => 
        [14] => 
    )
```

)

```
foreach ($xlsx->rows() as $key => $valueRows){

}




Array [0] => Array
(  
   [chair] => Array
        (
        [offer 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => AP1
                [1] => AP2
                [2] => AP3
                [3] => AP4
            )

        [offer 2] => Array
            (
                [0] => AP5
                [1] => AP6
                [2] => AP7
                [3] => AP8
                [4] => AP9
            )
         )

    [table] => Array
        (    
        [offer 1] => Array
            (
                [0] => AP10

            )


         ) 
 )
```

Comment: If your library for reading xlsx files works with the files you have I see no problem in doing it.

Comment: yes , I got array from EXCEL SHEET but how can create multidimensional array from it 

Category > No > Code

Comment: Could you edit you question and show us at least a part of the `$xlsx` array?

Comment: I added the XLXS Array. Please Check it above.

Comment: Either the library for reading xls is faulty or the sheet from the screenshot is different than the one you are running the script, because there's a fragment: `[1] => Array
([0] => Chair
[1] => Cover
[2] => 1
[3] => 
[4] => 
[5] => 
[6] => 
[7] => etge
[8] => 
[9] => 
[10] => 
[11] => 40%
[12] => 
[13] => 
[14] => 
)` - there's something like _cover_ and _etge_ which I don't see on the screenshot. Anyway it would be a mundane task to get your final table from the data you get from the SimpleXLSX library.